# How to wrap several TypeScript modules into groups for organization

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My TypeScript project has grown in to a moderate size and I'm trying to come up with a good way to organize it.

Right now, the project (an Angular 1.x app) is has the following structure:

```
-app/
 |
 |-components/
 | |
 | |-component A/
 | | |
 | | |-(..models..).ts
 | | |-(..services..).ts
 | |
 | |-component B/
 | | |
 | | |-(..models..).ts
 | | |-(..directives..).ts
 | |
 | (...)
 | |
 | |-component Z/
 | | |
 | | |-(..directives..).ts
 | | |-(..services..).ts
 | |
 | |-components.ts
 |
 |-app.ts
```

Basically, I've grouped app components logically so for instance a `Video` component will have its models and services declared in a single directory. I then load import all the components into a single file `app/components.ts` and re-export them.

```ts
 // models
 export * from './componentA/models.ts';
 export * from './componentB/models.ts';
 export * from './componentC/models.ts';

 // services
 export * from './componentA/services.ts';
 export * from './componentX/services.ts';
 export * from './componentZ/services.ts';

 // directives
 export * from './componentB/directives.ts';
 export * from './componentY/directives.ts';
 export * from './componentZ/directives.ts';
```

I'd then import the `app/components.ts` file in each of the component as well, since I almost always required multiple components in every time and importing each one individually would get very repetitive.

```ts
 // app/components/componentA/services.ts
 import * as ProjectName from '../components.ts';

 export class ComponentA_Service1 extends ProjectName.BaseService {

     protected $http: ng.IHttpService;
     protected $log: ng.ILogService;
     protected configService: ProjectName.ConfigService;

     /** @ngInject */
     constructor($http: ng.IHttpService, $log: ng.ILogService, ConfigService: ProjectName.ConfigService) {

         this.$http = $http;
         this.$log = $lot;
         this.configService = ConfigService;
     }

     // (.....)
 }

 export class ComponentA_Service2 { /* ... */ }
 export class ComponentA_Service3 extends ProjectName.ComponentZ_Service4 { /* ... */ }
```

This worked out well for a while, but now since the project has several dozen classes and interfaces defined. `ProjectName` becomes cluttered with dozens of members.

What I'd like is to group together different members based on what they are. For instance, a structure like:

```ts
 namespace ProjectName {

     namespace Models {

         class ComponentA_Model1 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentA_Model2 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentB_Model1 { /* ... */ }
     }

     namespace Services {

         class ComponentA_Service1 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentA_Service2 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentZ_Service4 { /* ... */ }
     }

     namespace Directives {

         class ComponentB_Directive1 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentY_Directive2 { /* ... */ }
         class ComponentZ_Directive3 { /* ... */ }
     }
 }
```

So far, I'm unable to figure out how to achieve that using TypeScript. More specifically, I'm unable to `import` several different modules and `export` them a single module.

Any ideas if it is even possible in TypeScript, or I'm heading in a completely wrong direction here?

---

**Update (January 31, 2016):** I thought I should add what I eventually ended up doing. I had already started trying an architecture similar to what was suggested by [@Vadim Macagon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042920/1304646) below. While it is the correct solution for what I was looking to do, I ultimately decided against it because of the reasons pointed out by [@mk.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35042640/1304646) in the accepted answer below.

I'm now importing individual modules from their respective directories directly in each file. While it is certainly a slight overhead when writing code, it is still the better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some suggestions:

1. Don't mix internal (namespaces) and external modules, pick one for your whole project and stick with it. Use external modules. Don't use namespaces/internal, except for declaration merging. See [this article](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2015/05/stop-mixing-typescript-internal-and-external-modules/) and others.
2. Don't re-export: it can make navigating to the original file more cumbersome, and breaks some tools (like find usages). It also creates two references to the same resource - the original, and the re-export. If your codebase invokes side-effects in one of the files, this can obscure the side-effects.

It seems that you're trying to minimize your imports, but the result is that you are importing everything in your project from one global "import registry" file.  Bulky definitions might be fine for certain well-composed `t.ds` files, but not for imports. Instead, think of modules as files, and import them individually, as needed:

```
import { MyClass } from "../foo/bar/MyClass";
import { toString, otherUtil } from "../foo/baz/Utils";
```

In other words, instead of using an import registry file, use the directory structure to group your files/modules. A minor but nice consequence of this is that you can write `extends BaseService` instead of always qualifying, as in `extends ProjectName.BaseService`. If you have too many imports (or too many exports) this suggests that the file might need to be broken up.

Comment: I'm actually not using namespaces at all. I just used that as an example to illustrate what I was trying to achieve. Your point about multiple references is something I didn't consider. I think I need to further study inner workings of TypeScript to better understand this.

Comment: You will be able to achieve the hierarchical grouping nicely using (time-tested) folders. Instead of `Foo.Bar.MyClass`, it will be `"foo/bar/MyClass"`. Good luck :)

Answer (score 5):

You're already familiar with re-exporting, so I believe something like this should work:

```
// models.ts
export * from './componentA/models.ts';
export * from './componentB/models.ts';
export * from './componentC/models.ts';

// services.ts
export * from './componentA/services.ts';
export * from './componentX/services.ts';
export * from './componentZ/services.ts';

// directives.ts
export * from './componentB/directives.ts';
export * from './componentY/directives.ts';
export * from './componentZ/directives.ts';

// projectname.ts
import * as Models from './models';
import * as Services from './services';
import * as Directives from './directives';

export { Models, Services, Directives };

// app.ts
import { Models, Services, Directives } from './projectname';
// OR
import * as ProjectName from './projectname';
```

Comment: This is actually what I've been experimenting with recently. It does get the job done, but has the overhead of creating several files only for re-exporting modules. I haven't committed to this approach yet since I'm not sure if this is really a good practice.

Comment: You should package all your build output into an ASAR anyway, at which point I doubt a few extra files will make much of an impact. Having said that @mk.makes some good points.